# Admob not showing ad - what does this log tell me?

Tags: android, ios, admob

My App has been showing Ads successfully for a couple months both on
iOS and Android. However, It just stopped last week to show anything.
I did not get any warning nor do I see anything on the Admob console
that something happened. I added the log flag to my iOS app and below
is what the logs show. I do not see an error

https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en

or anything obvious - but it's the first time and maybe I just don't see the obvious.

```
Connection to daemon was invalidated 2020-10-01 15:12:29.193111-0700
APP[85705:22999495] prepareInterstitial 2020-10-01
15:12:29.193191-0700 APP[85705:22999495] __cycleInterstitial
2020-10-01 15:12:29.195512-0700 APP[85705:22999495]
request.testDevices: 8AF59DD21920E0C3C4B8E65174A70515

2020-10-01 15:12:29.200845-0700 APP[85705:22999495] request.testDevices: 8AF59DD21920E0C3C4B8E65174A70515
2020-10-01 15:12:29.510454-0700 APP[85705:23001366] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
 filterBlacklist =     (
 );
 filterWhitelist =     (
 );
 restrictWeb = 1;
 useContentFilter = 0;
 useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
 whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2020-10-01 15:12:29.510530-0700 APP[85705:23001366] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-10-01 15:12:30.144653-0700 APP[85705:23001255] <Google> GMA Debug BEGIN
2020-10-01 15:12:30.144722-0700 APP[85705:23001255] <Google> GMA Debug CONTENT: {"components":["ad_request_7A5F6754-B123-4810-B1CD-93032189CBF0","network_request_12345678-CA45-4257-94E1-0FA9A5BD3305"],"timestamp":1601590350144.5598,"event":"onNetworkResponse","params":{"headers":[{"name":"Q29udGVudC1UeXBl","value":"dGV4dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PVVURi04"},{"name":"eC1hZm1hLWNvasdlbnQtdXJsLW9wdGVkLW91dA==","value":"dHJ1ZQ=="},{"name":"cDNw","value":"cG9saWN5cmVmPSJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZWFkcy5nLmRvdWQERFaWNrLm5ldC9wYWdlYWQvZ2NuX3AzcF8ueG1sIiwgQ1A9IkNVUmEgQURNYSBERVZhIFRBSW8gUFNBbyBQU0RvIE9VUiBJTkQgVU5JIFBVUiBJTlQgREVNIFNUQSBQUkUgQ09NIE5BViBPVEMgTk9JIERTUCBDT1Ii"},{"name":"YWx0LXN2Yw==","value":"aDMtUTA1MD0iZ29vZ2sdfgWRzLmcuZG91YmxlY2xpY2submV0OjQ0MyI7IG1hPTI1OTIwMDAsaDMtUTA1MD0iOjQ0MyI7IG1hPTI1OTIwMDAsaDMtMjk9Imdvb2dsZWFkcy5nLmRvdWJsZWNsaWNrLm5ldDo0NDMiOyBtYT0yNTkyMDAwLGgzLTI5PSI6NDQzIjsgbWE9MjU5MjAwMCxoMy0yNz0iZ29vZ2xlYWRzLmcuZG91YmxlY2xpY2submV0OjQ0MyI7IG1hPTI1OTIwMDAsaDMtMjc9Ijo0NDMiOyBtYT0yNTkyMDAwLGgzLVQwNTE9Imdvb2dsZWFkcy5nLmRvdWJsZWNsaWNrLm5ldDo0NDMiOyB
2020-10-01 15:12:30.144835-0700 
APP[85705:23001255] <Google> GMA Debug CONTENT: 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"},{"name":"eC14c3MtcHJvssdfVjdGlvbg==","value":"MA=="},{"name":"U2VysdfVy","value":"Y2FmZQ=="},{"name":"eC1hZm1hLWNvbnRlbnQtdmVydGljYWwtb3B0ZWQtb3V0","value":"dHJ1ZQ=="},{"name":"eC1hZm1hLXRlc3QtcmVxdWVzdA==","value":"dHJ1ZQ=="},{"name":"eC1hZm1hLWd3cy1xdWVyeS1pZA==","value":"VGxSMlgtYU1Bqwerf1aVFQTjZaSzREZw=="},{"name":"dGltaW5nLWFsbG93LW9yaWdpbg==","value":"Kg=="},{"name":"eC1hZm1hLW9uLWRldmljZS1icmFuZC1zYWZldHsdktb3B0ZWQtb3V0","value":"dHJ1ZQ=="},{"name":"RGF0ZQ==","value":"VGh1
2020-10-01 15:12:30.144945-0700 
APP[85705:23001255] <Google> GMA Debug CONTENT: LCAwMSBPY3QgMjAyMCAyMjoxMjozMCBHTVQ="},{"name":"Q29udGVudCadf1MZW5ndGg=","value":"MA=="},{"name":"eC1hZm1hasdLXVzZSqe1odHRwcw==","value":"ZmFsc2U="},{"name":"eC1jb250ZW50LXR5cGUtb3B0aW9ucw==","value":"bm9zbmlmZg=="}],"firstline":{"code":200}}}
2020-10-01 15:12:30.144969-0700 APP[85705:23001255] <Google> GMA Debug FINISH
```

Comment: Why does that have an android and an ios tag? It's clearly a problem with admob.

Comment: guess people who use admob develop for iOS and android, hence might come from that direction as well?

Answer (score 0):

I was poking around on the google mobile ads forum and they helped me. First of all, my Google libraries were not up2date after the iOS 14 release. Second of all, they had to fix something because after I got it working with the correct lib versions, it stopped again after one day and they had to fix something on their end.